# getting error 500 when trying to use gzip with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, gzip

I'm trying to use gzip on my site.

I'm trying to compress, php, css and js files. The server is apache 1.3, and the code I have in the .htaccess file is:

```
# compress all text & html:
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml
```

But when I upload this, I just get an Error 500 page.

Any ideas.

Comment: What does your Apache error log say? There's probably some more detail in there...

Comment: using the below doesn't seem to have any effect at all:

`<IfModule mod_gzip.c>
mod_gzip_on       Yes
mod_gzip_dechunk  Yes
mod_gzip_item_include file      \.(html?|txt|css|js|php|pl|jpg|png|gif)$
mod_gzip_item_include handler   ^cgi-script$
mod_gzip_item_include mime      ^text/.*
mod_gzip_item_include mime      ^application/x-javascript.*
mod_gzip_item_exclude mime      ^image/.*
mod_gzip_item_exclude rspheader ^Content-Encoding:.*gzip.*
</IfModule>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**AddOutputFilterByType** doesn't appear to be available on Apache 1.3 ([src](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#addoutputfilterbytype)). I believe you'll need to use [mod_gzip](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mod-gzip/) instead.

"Compatibility: Available in Apache 2.0.33 and later; deprecated in Apache 2.1 and later"

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
<Files *>
    #Compress
    SetOutputFilter GZIP
</Files>
```

Or this

```
<ifmodule mod_deflate.c>
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/text text/html text/plain text/xml text/css application/x-javascript application/javascript text/javascript
</ifmodule>
```