# 500 error when compressing files and using AddOutputFilterByType with .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I am using Apache 2.4 with PHP 5.5 on Windows Vista and trying to compress the files.

Here is my `.htaccess`

```
 RewriteEngine on
# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)?$ index.php/$1 [L]

# compress text, html, javascript, css, xml:
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
```

I have `mod_deflate`, `mod_header` and `mod_ext_filter` enabled in `httpd.conf`.

But the sever is returning 500 error.

Any Suggestions?

Comment: Suggestions: read the error log?

Answer (score 9):

You need to also enable `mod_filter` otherwise compression won't work.

Comment: this solves my problem, and should be marked as an answer as `AddOutputFilterByType` requires mod_filter

Answer (score 2):

Have you got mod_filter enabled?

This is *almost* a duplicate of the question ["getting error 500 when trying to use gzip with .htaccess"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2177860/getting-error-500-when-trying-to-use-gzip-with-htaccess) It says [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#addoutputfilterbytype) that AddOutputFilterByType is deprecated in Apache 2.1 and later, and it says [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_filter.html#addoutputfilterbytype) that it was moved to mod_filter in 2.3.7.

I got a 500 when I set this directive in my WAMP setup (Apache 2.4 on Win 7) with mod_deflate enabled; it disappeared when I enabled mod_filter.